# A noob but confusing question in Java Multithreading Programming

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to Java. I had a problem when learning Java multithreading programming, and here is the code:

```java
public class TestMultiThreads {
    private static int i = 100;
    private static Runnable r = () -> {
        while (i > 0) {
            i--;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

And the output is here: (not all the same but almost like this)

```
99
97
96
...
2
1
0
98
```

From what I learned, I know the 2 threads will preempt CPU time slices. However in this case, I cannot find any situation which can meet the output.

---

Update

Thank you everybody! With your help and I just now converted the .class file to Java bytecode and I think I have a guess. (or nearer to the truth)

it's part of the bytecode, `run()` method in `Runnable r`

```
  public void run();
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #2                  // Method top/littlefogcat/concurrent/TestMultiThreads.access$000:()I
       3: ifle          22
       6: invokestatic  #3                  // Method top/littlefogcat/concurrent/TestMultiThreads.access$010:()I
       9: pop
      10: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      13: invokestatic  #2                  // Method top/littlefogcat/concurrent/TestMultiThreads.access$000:()I
      16: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      19: goto          0
      22: return
```

I dont very understand Java bytecode, but can read some.

What I guess is that:
I maybe misunderstood how JVM allocate CPU time slices. I've thought that only when a thread finish executing one line of code can another thread has the chance to preempt CPU time slices. It's maybe wrong. One line of Java code may be converted to multiple lines of bytecode. JVM may allocate CPU time basing on smaller unit, such as a line of bytecode, or something else. Anyway, it's not safe to operate static variable in Java. It's necessary to use `synchronized` or other thread-safe ways.

And thank you guys

Comment: Try adding a `Thread.sleep` inside the `while-loop`, use something like 5-10 milliseconds and see what difference you get.  You could also increase the value of `i` and see if makes a difference

Comment: The output is probably legal since your code is not properly synchronized, but it's also surprising becaus the println method is synchronized.

Comment: @assylias yes I noticed that, that is why I was confused about the result

Comment: @NathanHughes Yes and that could lead to printing the same number twice. But I don't find a good explanation for the unordered but unique output.

Comment: @JingyiJiang Are you sure that, in your sample output, 98 was not printed twice?

Comment: @assylias 98 should have been after 99, however it appears at the end, which is not reasonable

Comment: @JingyiJiang "*98 should have been after 99*" what makes you think so? Notice that synchronization of `println` happens *after* method will be called, so it will already know value which it wants to print, but simply will need to wait for freeing monitor/lock of `System.out` object. Is there some guarantee/rule that processor will have to assign its time to t2 thread when monitor of `System.out` will be free?

Comment: There is no such thing as "reasonable" here. Anything which is not forbidden by the Java memory model and thread synchronization rules can and will happen.

Comment: In addition to the various methods available to achieve synchronization, I suggest you to check AtomicInteger class, it's very useful when dealing with multithreading and atomic increment/decrement ;)

Comment: @AlessioMoraschini got it :D

Comment: @AlessioMoraschini got it :D

Answer (score 2):

Look inside the `println` method:

```java
    /**
     * Prints an integer and then terminate the line.  This method behaves as
     * though it invokes {@link #print(int)} and then
     * {@link #println()}.
     *
     * @param x  The {@code int} to be printed.
     */
    public void println(int x) {
        synchronized (this) {
            print(x);
            newLine();
        }
    }
```

What you can see is that the value of `i` is copied into `x` when `println` is called. So when one thread calls the method with the value of `i` at a time, it could stop running right before `synchronized (this) {`. In the meantime another thread can do many prints but the value of `x` for the stopped thread will stay the same.

This will cause the strange order of prints and can even cause duplicated prints and skipped values when both threads enter the method at the exact same time. E.g. both increment `i` and then call `println` with it. When `i` got incremented two times, then obviously one value got skipped and both threads use the same `i` to be copied into `x`.

---

The root of the problem is that `i > 0`, `i--` and `println(i)` always need to be consistent. Those three operations need to be atomic. But in the given program they are not synchronized properly, thus the consistency is not enforced.

Here is an example of how to enforce the consistency:

```java
    private static int i = 100;
    private static final Object lock = new Object();
    private static Runnable r = () -> {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    i--;
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
```